# Authentication to online Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, java-api

I am authenticating with cookie to online Sharepoint, as answered here:

[REST - Authentication to online Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222917/rest-authentication-to-online-sharepoint)

When I try to authenticate I get 401 error.

This is my code:

```
   List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    //here I get cookie value
    CookieStore cookieStore = getCookieStore(.....);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
    String uri = URL  + "/" + "_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'" + FOLDER_NAME + "\')/files";        
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
    httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    httpGet.addHeader("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

    // Make the request.
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    // Process the result
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
       ......
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("", e);
}
```

My cookie store is something like this: [[version: 0][name: SPOIDCRL][value: 77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj.......

But, I am geting 401 with error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Again I can't authorise to SP. Can you help me one more time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried the Java client. But I can successfully issue the same request with the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) class in the .NET framework. Make sure the cookie has the format:

```
SPOIDCRL=77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48...
```

Also, you do not need to include the **X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED** header.